# How to do search on a table while table have millions of record

Tags: database, sybase

I have to run this below query in sybase database and this will return millions of record.
but when i run it took lot of time and many of times timeout.

```
select * from table1 t1
where t1.oneid IN
(
select t2.oneid 
from table2 t2
where t2.twoid IN 
(
    select DISTINCT t3.twoid from table3 t3 
 )
)
at isolation 0
```

so can any one suggest me a way so i can do some bulk operation for getting data?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT
    t1.*
FROM (
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT t3.twoid 
    FROM table3 t3 
) as tmp
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.twoid = tmp.twoid
INNER JOIN table1 t1
    ON t1.oneid = t2.oneid
```

It should be faster especially if you have indexes on `t2.twoid` and `t1.oneid`